# Settings management from code

Tags: android

I just want to ask you if you anyone knows how to change the Setting
available in:

`Settings->Wireless Settings->Mobile Network` from code or

```
Setting: Settings->Wireless Settings->Mobile Network Settings->Network
operators->Select Automatically?
```

I had been unable to find a property that match this setting in the

```
Settings.System / Settings.Secure classes.
```

Is there any alternative way to "turn on/off" the MOBILE
connectivity ?

The reason I need to solve this is to workaround the
bug occur during transitioning from WIFI to MOBILE that do not enable
CELL data automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think support for this sort of thing(changing settings from code) was removed/deprecated in the newer versions of the SDK; it is not advisable. What I've said is based on Dan Morill's Blog titled: [Future Proofing your Android Apps](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/future-proofing.html)

Eitherways, generally, you would write:

```
Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), <Settings.System.CONST>, <value>);
```

and have the following permission in your maifest: `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`
The List of Settings.System.CONST can be found in the official documentation: [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)